# Quadratic Diophantine Primality Testing

Tags: elementary-number-theory, computational-complexity

Define a 2-Quadratic Group Operation as the following:

A 2nd degree polynomial of the form:

$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_1^2 + a_4x_2^2 + a_5x_1x_2 $$

Define a primal 2-quadratic group number as an integer $Q$ such that:

There do not exist integers $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4,x_5)$ such that:

$$a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 + a_3x_1^2 + a_4x_2^2 + a_5x_1x_2 = Q $$

The set of primal 2-quadratic group numbers for the 2-quadratic group operation $xy$ is trivially the set of prime numbers.

The concept outlined here generalizes the prime numbers.

It is well known that the $xy$ primality of a number can be tested in polynomial time. Is it true therefore that the generic 2-quadratic group primality of a number can be tested in polynomial time?

My argument would be no, but it is weak as it simply assumes that P != NP which is not yet known to be true.

Is there any other way to verify this?

Comment: Does this require more explanation or is it clear as is?

Comment: When you write, "there do not exist integers $a_1,\dots,a_5$ such that....", do you mean, "there do not exist integers $x_1,x_2$ such that...."?

Comment: It seems to me that to determine whether $x^2+y^2=Q$ has a solution, one needs to factor $Q$ (as finding the residues mod 4 of the prime factors seems to be as hard as factoring), and no one knows how to factor in polynomial time.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson, that is correct, in regards to your second comment on the $x^2 + y^2 = Q$ being equivalent to factoring: I'm hoping that we can exploit properties of the primal elements over the group generated by $x^2 + y^2$ to create a AKS-like test that checks if Q is primal

Comment: So, you've changed $a_1,\dots,a_5$ to $x_1,\dots,x_5$ --- but there isn't any $x_3$ or $x_4$ or $x_5$. Also, are you aware that the word, "group", has a technical meaning in mathematics, and $x^2+y^2$ doesn't generate one, as far as I can see.

Comment: The substitution was done haphazardly as you have pointed out and I will correct, also I believe group is a set that is closed under a fixed operation between its elements which means that $x^2 + y^2$ as an operation with the proper primal elements is a generator for the set of integers, making it a proper group

Comment: You are welcome to your own beliefs, but if you want to talk mathematics you will find it more rewarding if you use words the same way the rest of us do. We use "group" to refer to a set closed under an associative binary operation with an identity element and with every element having an inverse.

Comment: What would be the formal term for what I have describe then?

Comment: Your quadratic (where you still haven't edited out those superfluous variables) defines a binary operation on the integers.